# Detecting if selected item is in a datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of JQuery that I am trying to use to detect if the value that is in a data list select box is actually in the list, here is what i have.

```
<div class='form-row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required' style="margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <h2>
            <label class='control-label' style="font-size: 20px;">
                Product code
            </label>
        </h2>
        <input required id="ItemSelect" list=jobs style='font-size:21px;height: 40px;' class='form-control' name="Code">
        <datalist id="jobs">
            <?php
                foreach ($this->Products as $a) {
                    $inputValue = "  " . htmlentities($a["Code"] . " | " . $a["Name"]) . " ";
                    echo '<option>' . $inputValue;
                }
            ?>
        </datalist>
    </div>
```

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var datalistval = $('#ItemSelect').val();
    console.log(datalistval);
    console.log($("#ItemSelect option[value='" + datalistval + "']").length)

    if ($("#ItemSelect option[value='" + datalistval +  "']").val() === undefined) {
        console.log("not there");
    } else {
        console.log(" there");
    }
});
```

currently with this if i enter a value that is not in the list it comes back as no there, but it also comes back as not there if i do select one out of the list.

Here out the outputs of the console.logs

```
console.log(datalistval); // X01A172 | Sub Assembly 2
console.log($("#ItemSelect option[value='" + datalistval + "']").length) // 0  
not there
```

Comment: function val() returns null when there is no option selected

Comment: @MauricePerry there is an option selected, console.log(datalistval); shows what is selected

Comment: Your test is nonetheless wrong.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: val() will either return null, or datalistval

Comment: Id for the list is jobs so you need `#jobs` and not `#ItemSelect option`.

Comment: i did'nt see any '#submit' in the code.Then how will onclick() will work?